# erase rows when a variable is equal to 0 but not when it is NA , or when two columns are equal to NA in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset df that looks like this

```
rel freq key
1.1 1.1 a       
1   1   b       
1   NA  c       
NA  NA  d       
NA  0   e       
NA  1   f
```

I want to obtain this:

```
rel freq key
1.1 1.1 a       
1   1   b       
1   NA  c               
NA  1   f
```

basically I want to get rid of the rows where `freq` = 0 or the rows where both `rel` and `freq` are equal to NA.

I tried

```
df <- df[df$freq!=0,]
```

to filter out freq = 0 but it gives me some problems

similarly

```
library(dplyr)
df <- filter(df, freq != 0)
```

eliminates all the rows with `freq` = NA

Any suggestion on how I can solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
subset(df, !(freq == 0 & !is.na(freq) | (is.na(freq) & is.na(rel))))
```

Output:

```
  rel freq key
1 1.1  1.1   a
2 1.0  1.0   b
3 1.0   NA   c
6  NA  1.0   f
```

Or in `dplyr`:

```
dplyr::filter(df, !(freq == 0 & !is.na(freq) | (is.na(freq) & is.na(rel))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df[!(!is.na(df$freq) & df$freq == 0 | (is.na(df$freq) & is.na(df$rel))),]

#   rel freq key
# 1 1.1  1.1   a
# 2 1.0  1.0   b
# 3 1.0   NA   c
# 6  NA  1.0   f
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(rel = c(1.1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA),
                 freq = c(1.1, 1, NA, NA, 0, 1),
                 key = letters[1:6])
```